# SharePoint view access control

Tags: sharepoint, jquery-selectors

I have the following requirement to fulfill:

I have a view group by "Project" column. Current logged in user need to expand only a project that he/she belongs to (I have a way to get the user's project). The grouped projects have the following forms:

```
<td nowrap="" class="ms-gb" colspan="100"><img width="0" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><a onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('1-2_','img_1-2_');return false;" href="javascript:"><img border="0" alt="Expand/Collapse" src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif" id="img_1-2_"></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('1-2_','img_1-2_');return false;" href="javascript:">Project</a> :&nbsp;<a href="[mysite]&amp;RootFolder=*">Project1</a> <span style="font-weight: lighter">&lrm;(2)</span></td>


<td nowrap="" class="ms-gb" colspan="100"><img width="0" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><a onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('1-3_','img_1-3_');return false;" href="javascript:"><img border="0" alt="Expand/Collapse" src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif" id="img_1-3_"></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('1-3_','img_1-3_');return false;" href="javascript:">Project</a> :&nbsp;<a href="[mysite]&amp;RootFolder=*">Project2</a> <span style="font-weight: lighter">&lrm;(1)</span></td>
```

Tried the following but disables all project links:
$('td:contains("Project1") td.ms-gb a').removeAttr("onclick").click(function() { return false; });

Also when a user clicks on project that he/she don't have access to, I need to throw out a message "you do not have access to this project...".

All helps are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to disable the specified project group linke, use this (project1 for ex.):

```js
$("td:contains('Project1')>a").removeAttr("onclick");
```

I haven't found out how to change items links' behavior under a certen group. But, even if we can do that, we still can't prevend unauthorized users to access the project items through url directly. The best solution is to stop those items permission inherit and give access permisson only to those people who supposed to read or write the items.